# How can I play Police Quest I on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, dos, police-quest

How can I get [*Police Quest: In Pursuit of the Death Angel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_Quest%3a_In_Pursuit_of_the_Death_Angel) to run on a Windows 7 64-bit machine? I used to have this game when I was a kid and want to give it another go.

Comment: A *what*? The suspense is killing me!

Comment: Have you tried and it doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried [DOSBox](http://dosbox.com)?

Comment: I will try dosbox thanks. Otherwise I will buy the full series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in luck.

GOG.com sells the entire Police Quest series for ten bucks [on their website](http://www.gog.com/gamecard/police_quest_1_2_3_4). This includes launchers that'll let you run the games in Windows 7.

Comment: Do note that the version of PQ1 included in that collection is the point-and-click "remake" version from the 90s, and not the original 1987 version. (This is also often holds true for other similar Sierra anthologies, such as recent King's Quest re-releases.)

Comment: @cloudymusic: According to the [GOG forums](http://www.gog.com/forum/police_quest_series/police_quest_14_updated_orginal_ega_pq1_added), the EGA original was added a few weeks ago.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen: Awesome! I'll have to go back and revisit it now, as that's my favorite game in the series. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather comment this but I can not comment yet, probably too low rep.

GOG.com sells it but here you can get the installers for free if you own the original version(s). Lots of sierra games made compatible even for X64 systems. May need some fiddling with some settings though.

http://www.sierrahelp.com/Patches-Updates/NewSierraInstallers.html#PQ

Comment: Seems like it would work for the supported games in the list but of course the best one (PQ: SWAT 2) doesn't have an installer.

Comment: @Lilienthal A more advanced way would be to use dosbox. Lookup how to install and play old dos games with the program called "dosbox". I cannot guarantee success but with some PC knowledge and affert you probably manage to run it good enough to be playable.

Comment: That's true for the older games but SWAT 2 is a Windows game. The problem is the 16bit installer but there might be [an advanced workaround](http://www.reactos.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=10988) after all.